# navigate without losing data ionic typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

How can go from current page to previous page after selecting information in the current page, without losing those information when I return to this current page. In fact ngoninit, initialize the default information.
I need some help

Comment: There is an awesome way to manage it using state management : https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Comment: I think that ionic is also working with routes and routeParams, so you could push your data through the routeParams to another page. Have a look at this: https://ionicacademy.com/pass-data-angular-router-ionic-4/